# what would be the path for the file in the root directory?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have learned, placing the mysqli connection config.php file in the root directory(out of the public html) for  security purpose. So, if I want to include config.php before the query what would be the path?

my config.php is as follows

```
              <?php
              $hostname='';
              $username='';
              $password='';
              $database_name='';


             $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database_name); 
             ?>
```

In my other php file

```
             <?include('config.php');?>
```

my config.php is in the root directory. what would be the path in include statement?

Comment: You can go from document root: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and then add the right navigation to the nested directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "root directory" that usually means the root directory of a filesystem.  On most *nix (Linux, FreeBSD, Unix) installs, that means your filesystem path is simply "/".  That is, if your config file is there, your PHP file should look like this:

```
<?php
    include('/config.php');
?>
```

However, it would generally be both a bad idea and would require superuser privileges to actually put a file at the filesystem root of "/".  So it's likely (but we have to guess), that you mean the DOCUMENT ROOT for your web server.  Most web servers running PHP make that value available via the super-global $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as mentioned by Kai Qing in his comment.  If that is where your file is, then you could put this in your PHP file:

```
<?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');
?>
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php .

Comment: Also, just an FYI for OP, if you have a file outside of the document root, you can still do `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../someOtherPath/config.php'` to access files outside of the document root (and relative to the document root). PHP will interpret the `..` as one level above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php')

http://css-tricks.com/php-include-from-root/

This link has another technique as well, if your DOCUMENT_ROOT is not set properly.